# Can't authenticate against multiple models in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, eloquent

I'm trying to set up authentication for both superadmins and users (separate tables) in my app, but it's not behaving as expected. Authentication against the `User` model works fine, but not against the `Superadmin` model. My models are as follows:

User.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

Superadmin.php:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Superadmin extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = 'superadmin';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

My config/auth.php:

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'superadmin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'superadmins',
        ],
        'superadmin-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'superadmins'
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'superadmins' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Superadmin::class,
        ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
        'superadmins' => [
            'provider' => 'superadmins',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 15,
        ],
    ],

];
```

Seems right to me, but apparently not, as the following happens after entering correct creds for a superadmin user: [image: failed superadmin login]

Entering creds for a regular user works as expected: [image: successful user login]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Take a look at the `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php` class, and `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php` You will see you need to pass a name to the 'guard'

Answer (score 0):

If you go

`vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php`

You will see a method called `attemptLogin`

Which has

```
/**
 * Attempt to log the user into the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return bool
 */
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );
}
```

Now, if you go the `guard` method, it uses

```
/**
 * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
 */
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard();
}
```

Now, if you delve further in to the

`vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php` you will see the 'guard method' expects a `$name`

```
/**
 * Attempt to get the guard from the local cache.
 *
 * @param  string  $name
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard|\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
 */
public function guard($name = null)
{
    $name = $name ?: $this->getDefaultDriver();

    return $this->guards[$name] ?? $this->guards[$name] = $this->resolve($name);
}
```

Now, look at the `getDefaultDriver` method, which gets the default value from the auth config file:

```
/**
 * Get the default authentication driver name.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getDefaultDriver()
{
    return $this->app['config']['auth.defaults.guard'];
}
```

In your auth.php add:

```
'login' => [
    'guard' => [
        'web',
    ]
],
```

So, in your `logincontroller.php`, you can override the guard method to use your specific guard:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Modules\Core\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }


    /**
     * Attempt to log the user into the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        foreach(config('auth.login.guard') as $guard) {
            return $this->guard($guard)->attempt(
                $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
            );
        }

        return false;
    }

        /**
     * Send the response after the user was authenticated.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
    {
        $request->session()->regenerate();

        $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

        foreach(config('auth.login.guard') as $guard) {
            return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
                    ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
        }

        return false;
    }

        /**
     * Log the user out of the application.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        foreach(config('auth.login.guard') as $guard) {
            $this->guard($guard)->logout();
        }

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        return redirect('/');
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard($name = null)
    {
        return Auth::guard($name);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but adding this method to LoginController.php causes the following error: Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Auth' not found

Comment: You need to include the auth facade, at the top `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
`

Comment: Ok, so it's working better now, but still not quite right. I am no longer getting the "wrong creds" message, but I'm being immediately redirected back to the login page and not logged in. Also, this now makes it so I can't log in as a regular user, right?

Comment: "you can override this, to select from all 3, with a custom select", I'm a bit confused about what you mean by this.

Comment: @BrandonM. See the updated answer, in the auth.php add your guards to the new array.